# setLSActiveProject failed: Error: Starting server failed

Tags: uno-platform

Building an app for Android using MAUI for my app [Conference Live Captioning](https://conferencecaptioning.com). So I decided to try the Uno Platform VS Code extension. It gave me a few errors that I was able to resolve by googling online, but then I got this when I tap the "Enable" button in the Extensions menu [image]

```
[Info] Using 'ms-dotnettools.csharp' version 2.0.399.
[Info] Requesting available projects from OmniSharp
[Info] Setting active project /Users.../BeAware/BeAware.csproj
[Error] setLSActiveProject failed: Error: Starting server failed
Uno Platform "dotnet new" templates are already installed. The templates may be updated by running "dotnet new install Uno.Templates"
```

I tried to google the error, but I couldn't find anything online. I did make sure that VSCode opens the directory that contains the SLN file as well

Comment: Have you run uno-check first on that machine? Is it all green? https://platform.uno/docs/articles/external/uno.check/doc/using-uno-check.html

Comment: @JérômeLaban thanks for the response ! Yes, apart from  GTK3+, they were all checks and fixed

Comment: Link to issue https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/13881